# Create an event in excel - add value to cell X after input on cell Y -> clean cell Y

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Basically, what i want to do is:

Whenever i insert values in column B, it add the value to column A and then sets the column B to 0.

```
A    B

23   0
```

I tried this function(passing A as uni and B as new_value), but it doesn't work...

```
Function foo(uni, new_value)
    uni = uni + new_value
End Function
```

Comment: Well, if it gave you some error then I'm sure there is some answer.

Comment: well it doesn't give an error anymore, but still not working the way it should...
It is even possible to achieve what i am trying?

Answer (score 0):

OK. Here is how but this is untested because I can't be bothered to load Excel.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will 
    ' cause an alert when they are changed. Edit as needed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("B2:B10")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
      ' This code is only ran when one of the above cells change
      cells(Target.Row, 1).value = cells(Target.Row, 2).value
     cells(Target.Row, 2).value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```